# Resources and information on making a Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am a newbie/wannabe Full Stack Javascript Developer and I am going through the motions of writing an application, the JS itself isnt extraordinarily difficult, the hard part (at least to me) is the syntax of incorporating all of these dependencies. For instance I am using:

- Express
- EJS
- RethinkDB
- PapaParse
- passport
- socket.io

This is just what I have so far that I know I need, Im sure before I am done I'll need 10 more.

Why are there so little tutorials/documentation on how to use all of these different dependencies together? As someone trying to learn I find it hard to perform the tasks that I need to do without a lot of online looking, searching and whatnot.

At the same time I ask this question I understand that just the simple fact that there are so many makes it hard to do any good learning with my or another exact stack. But that being said there are generalities, like Express and Socket.io with passport are pretty popular I would think. Rethink is a new company but still I find that trying to use EJX with rethink and passport is hard to figure out the syntax.

Does anyone know any real good resources dedicated to the Node platform and this NPM environment? If I were to add Handlebars to this mix I would be even more confused. Obviously I am not a rockstar developer, nor someone who this comes very easily to. I have taken a few very good video courses that explain things well and I understand those concepts but they are few and far between so the gaps between the technologies are huge.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes. **Start small**. Add one component to the stack at a time. Build a *simple* express server. Talk to it from the browser via ajax. Use chrome so you have the devtools and ES6 without any build process. Then add persistence, etc. Trying to do this all at once is a recipe for failure. The reason there aren't any tutorials on how to do all this at once is that no one does all this all at once.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at some better done boilerplates. There a ton of them from github such as [hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter). While they may not have all the best practices and some of them are quite opinionated, it's a good jumping off point.

Another one is to look at open source projects and other well known frameworks at how they set projects up. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) is a really good one. Even though it's in PHP, but the app structure and the expressive naming is very easy to read, making a lot of sense. Honestly, I think Laravel is probably one of the best done frameworks for web sites/apps. It's a shame there isn't something quite as comprehensive for Node.

It looks like you are using express for the main library. Take the time to read through their guides, such as the [template engine guide](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html). I can't say too much for the other stuff one since I don't use them, but I do use socket.io a lot. If you want your socket to use your express server:

```
// SERVER
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on 3000');
});

// SOCKET
var io = socket.listen(server); // then use 'io' according to socket.io docs
```

Finally, I would say. Take all of these sources with a grain of salt. While there certainly are best practices, you also have to consider what make sense to you and your projects. Really think through why each framework or boilerplate is structured the way it is. Only then can you think for yourself and find the best solution for you,

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I understand the workflow of the files, its just the syntax of the individual dependencies and how they interact with each other. To your point about using resources with a grain of salt, I am trying to NOT use many dependencies. I am really trying to learn the basic lower level aspects before I start implementing some abstractions.

Comment: In that case, I would really recommend looking at boilerplates and example projects. Here is a good selection of [boilerplates from express wiki](https://github.com/expressjs/express/wiki?_ga=1.179348132.1441327556.1469257237#boilerplate). Especially the files like `server.js` or `app.js` or `app/index.js`, those usually have a good selection of how modules are hooked with each other.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks like a great resource.